# ExtJS Chart No Colour

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create a chart panel, my chart is pie-chart, the chart only display the values and everything else but no color, how or where do I assign color for my chart.

```
    border: 0,
    items: [{
          xtype: 'chart',
          height: 400,
          width: 800,
          padding: '10 0 0 0',
          style: 'background: #fff',
          animate: true,
          shadow: false,
          store: store,
          insetPadding: 40,
          legend: {
             field: 'task',
             position: 'bottom',
             boxStrokeWidth: 0,
             labelFont: '12px Helvetica'
          },
          ....
          series: [{
              type: 'pie',
              angleField: 'durations',
              label: {
                  field: 'task',
                  display: 'outside',
                  calloutLine: true
              },
              showInLegend: true,
              highlight: {
                 segment: {
                    margin: 50
                 }
              },
              tips: {
                 trackMouse: true,
                 renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                     this.setTitle(storeItem.get('task') + ': ' + storeItem.get('durations') + ' Days');
                 }
              }
           }]
       }]
```

Please assist...

Comment: Can you please create a https://fiddle.sencha.com/ with your code.

Comment: I think the main problem is the panel background, when I add ""Save Chart" functionality, the chart is printed nicely with all colors